# Jsonwebtoken : invalid token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I setup JWT in my express app and I get this error : `invalid token`. But when I copy this token to jwt.io, exp date is correct and data ok.

Here is my controller :

```
module.exports.signIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "User not found."
    });
  }

  const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!isValidPassword) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Invalid password."
    });
  }

  const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "10h"
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    message: "User logged in.",
    token
  });
};
```

And my middleware :

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports.verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization;
  console.log(token);

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      message: "No token provided."
    });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Unauthorized."
      });
    }

    req.userId = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
};
```

What I do is :

- sign in
- copy token to Headers authorizations
- make my get request to another route that has the `verifyToken`

And then I get the error.

When I `console.log(token)` I get `Bearer ...[the token]`

Any idea why ?

Comment: you need to remove the `Bearer ` prefix from the token when using it on the backend. The same way you would remove `Basic ` from a basic auth string before using it.

Comment: You mean, in postman I have to remove the Bearer that Postman set automatically ?

Comment: No, I mean in the backend you need to remove it. The token itself does not contain Bearer, thats part of the http protocol to some extend. Thefore, when the request reaches your backend, you need to extract the token from the auth header, so that there is no bearer prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need four arguments in the verify function

```
jwt.verify(token, process.env.PUBLIC_KEY, {}, (err, decoded) => {

                if (err !== null && err instanceof TokenExpiredError) {
                    cb('TOKEN_EXP');
                    return Json.builder(Response.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED_TOKEN_EXP);
                }

                if (err instanceof JsonWebTokenError) {
                    cb('IN_VALID_TOKEN');
                    return Json.builder(Response.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED_INVALID_TOKEN);
                }

                cb(decoded);
            });
```